# On adding nested linearLayout under existing linear layout, error: "applicaton has stopped, force closing"

Tags: android

Please see the code. If I remove my additions..   the code is working fine I am trying to add one text field under linear layout.. Please see the comments in code
               This is the working code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:orientation = "vertical">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/RootFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "42dip">  

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RootTextView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" 
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:lines="2"/>  
             <!--If we insert the New code then not working (new code find below)-->  

                   </FrameLayout>  

        <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/RootFrameLayout2"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:background = "@drawable/pink.bg"
        adroid:layout_gravity = "top" >  

        <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar1"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:background = "@drawable/pink.bg"
        adroid:layout_gravity = "center" />  

        </FrameLayout>  
        </LinearLayout>
```

### New Code: If we add the following code in the working code. apllications is force closing.

```
        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Linearlayout1"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:visiblity ="invisible">  

        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/LinearTextView"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />  

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Paste the working code and then the non-working code

Comment: Nargis... I have added both the codes.. Could you please have a look on it?

Comment: Can anyone please lookover the issue suggest me the solution?

Comment: Very Unclear why you are putting a Linear Layout inside a FrameLayout and that too invisible!!